# Entity framework cashing list if manipulated during same dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the strangest problem. When I do `ToList()`on a `IQueryble`collection, brackets in the collection (and content between the brackets) are mysteriously removed.

```
    public IEnumerable<SurveyQuestion> GetByPeriodId(int peridId)
    {
        IQueryable<SurveyQuestion> list = Find(x => x.PeriodId == peridId);

        var items = list.ToList();

        return items;
    }
```

`list` contains the following sql statement

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Question] AS [Question], 
[Extent1].[SurveyAnswerTypeId] AS [SurveyAnswerTypeId], 
[Extent1].[ReportQuestionId] AS [ReportQuestionId], 
[Extent1].[SurveyTemplateQuestionId] AS [SurveyTemplateQuestionId], 
[Extent1].[PeriodId] AS [PeriodId], 
[Extent1].[MaxPoint] AS [MaxPoint]
FROM [dbo].[SurveyQuestion] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[PeriodId] = 1062
```

One of the question columns contains

"Here are some things: [Car, Knife, House]"

But after doing `ToList()` on the collection the string is changed to

"Here are some things:"

What is going on here?!

Comment: `ToList` will not change the data.  It will just run the query and populate the data into a list.  How do you verify that the data in the DB is one thing and another in your list?  Can you check the code for the property of `SurveyQuestion` in question to see if something is going on there?

Comment: Most likely scenario: you have two items "Here are some things: [Car, Knife, House]" (with a `PeriodId` different than `peridId`) & "Here are some things:" (with a `PeriodId` equal to `peridId`). Better check the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. The thing was that Entity Framework was cashing the list `items` since this was manipulated during the same `DbContext`. So it didn't populate the list with items from the database. It kept the old, changed list.

Powerful if you use it well, but confusing if you (like me) don't expect that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `ToList()` on queryable you are **executing** query. I.e. SQL query is sent to database server, query is executed there, results are downloaded and mapped to in-memory entities. And you get list of `SurveyQuestion` entities (if SQL query has some results). If you want to dump results of query to string you can iterate them and save each object to string or you can serialize results. E.g. getting questions:

```
string questions = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Select(i => i.Question));
```

or you can iterate items and read their questions

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   string question = item.Question;
   // ...
}
```